# Why isn't this sending an HTTP POST request in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I've looked up and found a few different methods of sending HTTP POST requests through a VB.NET program, however none of them are working for me. 
Here is the current one I'm trying, can anyone tell me why it isn't working?

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim postData As String = "exampleid=454621696&text=yesitworked"
        Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
        Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

        Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://website.com/comments/post/"), HttpWebRequest)
        postReq.Method = "POST"
        postReq.KeepAlive = True
        postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        postReq.Referer = "https://website.com"
        postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
        postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length

        Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
        postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
        postreqstream.Close()
        Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse

        postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())

        Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd

        RichTextBox1.Text = thepage

    End Sub
End Class
```

From what I've seen I think it just isn't sending the request, because it does throw an error when it tries to get a response, but like I said I think it's because the request isn't even running.

Thanks

Comment: Check out the MSDN example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.100).aspx. You can download PostMan, and test the post request, to make sure the server response correctly first

Comment: @Jacky thanks, I will try that code. I have tested the request and confirmed it works.

Comment: Anyway, if it's allowed to add 3rd party library, I suggest you try RestSharp http://restsharp.org instead of using .net

Comment: @Jacky alright, my .net really isn't working out. Unless someone else can point out what's wrong, I'll use RestSharp. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacky I'm having trouble using RestSharp, I can't find any tutorials to send HTTP POST requests in VB.NET with it. If you know of one, please tell me. Thanks

Comment: Basically, Vb.net and Asp.net will work the same, you just need to change the syntax. Can see 1 example from OP here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845205/restsharp-deserialization-containing-both-a-value-and-a-dictionary-under-the-roo If you have any trouble, you can post in StackOverflow again :)